# Semaphore dynamic resizing C#

Tags: c#, dynamic, semaphore, resize

I'm trying to use semaphores to control how many instances of a job can be run at the same time. While this is fairly simple with a wait method, I also want the value to be configurable at runtime so that I can bump the count up or down.

I realize that there may be issues bumping the count down but is there a way to actually do this? Is this the right approach to be using semaphores?

Comment: When you say "instances of a job", are you talking about multiple processes or a single process?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> While this is fairly simple with a wait method, I also want the value to be configurable at runtime so that I can bump the count up or down.

I would not recommend using semaphores for this.

If you're in .NET 4, my suggested method would be to create a custom [TaskScheduler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.taskscheduler.aspx) which would allow you to change the level of concurrency at runtime.  You could then run your entire operation using a single `Parallel.For`/`ForEach` call passing this TaskScheduler in the options, and change the level of concurrency at runtime.

This would make it fairly easy to handle moving levels up or down.  When levels go up, you just add new threads as needed.  When they go down, just remove that thread from your internal collection (but don't stop it), and let it finish its current work.  This would allow you to scale as needed.

Comment: In the current days, I would strongly recommend NOT using custom task schedulers for this, especially in the async/await world and especially if you're using other 3rd party libraries which you have no control over. It can cause deadlocks very easily when the limit of concurrent tasks has been hit. The custom task scheduler will get propagated in the execution context, and any code creating tasks in the same flow will use it.

Comment: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/fkaduk/2018/09/02/multiple-ways-how-to-limit-parallel-tasks-processing/

Answer (score 4):

According to the documentation of [ReleaseSemaphore](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms685071%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), for the `lReleaseCount` parameter:

> The amount by which the semaphore object's current count is to be increased. The value must be greater than zero. **If the specified amount would cause the semaphore's count to exceed the maximum count that was specified when the semaphore was created, the count is not changed and the function returns FALSE.**

This, and other documentation suggests that a semaphore is not the right choice for your limitation. A semaphore, once created, has a hard maximum that cannot be changed without recreating the semaphore. In other words, **it is not a dynamic value that can be changed**.

You need to find another way of managing your limit in this scenario.

One way you *could* use a semaphore would be to allocate a semaphore that is *big enough* for all future needs, and then just grab enough "instances" of it to reduce the available number back down to what you need at the moment. When you want to increase the number of available instances, just release some of those you grabbed at the beginning.

However, I question why you want to do this. What is the limiting factor that really decides how many jobs you can execute at the same time here? Most likely a semaphore is not the right answer to this.